# In python, an instance A can be revised by another one B after you let B=A? Why?

Tags: python, linked-list, instance

In the following code, I'm creating a head node of linked list. But I don't know why the '.next' of 'head' can be update(iterated) by update 'tail' and 'tail.next':

```
# Node class
class Node(object):
   def __init__(self,x):
     self.val = x
     self.next = None

# For a given list, creat a head node of it
def creat_link_tail(val_list):
   head = Node(val_list[0])
   tail = head
   for ele in val_list[1:]:
     tail.next = Node(ele)
     tail = tail.next
return head

lkt = creat_link_tail([5, 3, 2, 6, 7])  #lkt 5->3->2->6->7
```

Comment: The whole point is that each link points to the next.  When you're done, `lkt.next.next.next.next.next` is equal to `lkt`.  Even though there are no named objects that refer to those intermediate nodes, you can find them by following the links.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! But I just can't understand why the 'head' instance can be reviesed by revising 'tail'. Is it beacause they share the same memory space? @Tim Roberts

Comment: The relationship between variables and objects doesn't work like you think it does. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: After those first two statements, `head` and `tail` are both bound to the same object.  Updating either one updates the object.  During the loop, we change `tail` so that it is bound to other objects.  After the first loop, `head` and `tail` no longer point to the same object.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica, thanks for sharing, I've learned  a lot from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't know why the '.next' of 'head' can be update(iterated) by update 'tail' and 'tail.next':

You stored the very fist element in `head`:

```
head = Node(val_list[0])
```

Then you assigned it as the initial value of `tail`:

```
tail = head
```

Now, `tail` and `head` points to the exact same object in memory which stores the same instance of `Node(val_list[0])`. To visualize this, we can inspect the memory used.

```
class Node(object):
   def __init__(self,x):
     self.val = x
     self.next = None

head = Node(0)
tail = head

print(id(head))  # Memory pointed to by head
print(id(tail))  # Memory pointed to by tail
print(head is tail)  # Checks if head is the same as tail
```

**Output**

```
22809434462432
22809434462432
True
```

As you can see, they are just point to the exact same object. They are different stack variables `head` and `tail` but their value points to the same object in heap. Thus accessing the pointed object via `.` from one variable e.g. `tail.next = Node(ele)` is like indirectly calling `head.next = Node(ele)`.

Now let's try to change the value of the stack variable `tail` and point it to another object.

```
tail = Node(0)

print(id(head))
print(id(tail))
print(head is tail)
```

**Output**

```
22809434462432
22809434463632
False
```

Now as you can see, the pointed object by `head` and `tail` are now different.